# Why does Error: Could not find or load main class SearchResults occur?

Tags: java, jvm, classpath

I was writing the code with java programming language.

After I finished writing, I compiled the code with the following command:

```
javac BingImageSearch.java -classpath ./gson-2.8.1.jar -encoding UTF-8 -Xlint:deprecation
```

Then I used the command below to run the java program:

```
java -cp ./gson-2.8.1.jar BingImageSearch
```

But it shows the error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class BingImageSearch
```

Everything looks correct, my `gson-2.8.1.jar` file is in the same directory as the java file.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java uses current folder "." as a class path by default.

When you tell JVM to use some specific jar file as a class path then it ignores current folder.

You need to combine several locations (both JAR file and current folder) for java to find all required class files.

Proper command line to run your app needs to be:

```
java -cp .:./gson-2.8.1.jar BingImageSearch
```